# ng-model not updating instantly while using IE11

Tags: jquery, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to clear off list of check-boxes all at once under a radio (option - 'Yes') when option 'No' is selected:

```js
if (checkbox unchecked) {
    //adding checkbox to list of checkboxes selected
} 
else {
  //taking off only the checkbox which is unchecked
  //If No trying to clear off the whole list of checkboxes under Yes to " "
  if (radioVal == 'No') 
  {
    list = [];
  }
}
```

When using Chrome radioVal is populating as 'No'. But when using IE11, the radioVal is still populating as 'Yes' and this code is clearing off only one checkbox at a time.

Any help?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to reproduce it in IE 11 ?

Comment: sorry, I cant provide one. Would love to know if you know anything about this issue.